# mqt_native_modules react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'w.default.chapterContent[c].content')

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

React Native app is crashing when I click into a new view. However, the stack trace shows no leads to my code, so I'm not sure how to debug. Can someone point me the right way, or let me know if I should report a bug to React Native?

Error and full stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myappname, PID: 6115
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'w.default.chapterContent[c].content')
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: 
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: This error is located at:
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in c
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in AndroidHorizontalScrollContentView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in AndroidHorizontalScrollView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in E
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in z
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in _
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in u
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in o
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTScrollView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in E
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in n
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in l
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in s
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in u
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in C
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in n
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in E
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in n
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in H
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in L
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in h
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in v
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in h
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in _
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in N
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in n
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in D
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in h
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in c
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: 
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: This error is located at:
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in N
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in n
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in D
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in h
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in RCTView
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:     in c, stack:
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: renderItem@628:716
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: value@632:19530
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: value@247:22532
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Cr@90:49183
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Ji@90:70549
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Ki@90:71041
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Ua@90:77455
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Na@90:76778
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Ie@90:84181
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Me@90:13520
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: Oe@90:13693
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: receiveTouches@90:14462
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:3311
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@28:822
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:2565
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: value@28:794
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime: 
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
04-21 17:47:34.000  6115  6143 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

What I've tried:
 1. I've googled mqt_native_modules and see that for many, the problem is with React/React Native. Is there way to find out if mine is also a problem with React Native, or should I just file a bug?
 2. I searched my repo for `w.default.chapterContent[c].content` but the closest snippets are `const { content } = ContentService.chapterContent[chapterId];` and `this.chapterContent[doc.id]`

Here is one of the components:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import ContentService from '../services/ContentService';

export default class Conclusion extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const { chapterId } = ContentService.chapterDataMap['conclusion'];
    const { content } = ContentService.chapterContent[chapterId];
    this.state = { content };
  }
  render() {
    const { content } = this.state;

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        <Text style={styles.module}>{content}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

The service is working for iOS.

Comment: if you could share that component, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: it indeed wasn't a code problem. I was working with a team while splitting Android and iOS responsibilities. The iOS side had put in the necessary data, but we were using different Firebase accounts.

Comment: can you please elaborate this more I am facing the same problem. How it is related to Firebase account?

Comment: @VikasGoyal -- in my case, `default.chapterContent[c].content` was accessing something in Firebase. Since I was hooked up to a different Firebase that didn't have that datastore, it errored.